# How to make a entire span drop into a new line?

Tags: html, css

This snippet shows what i want:
http://jsfiddle.net/945Df/3/

```
<div class="sup" id="pr">
    <strong>
        <a href="#">Rosario, Santa Fe, Argentina.</a> <span class="date">17 de septiembre de 2013.</span></strong>
</div>
<div class="sup">
    <strong>
        <a href="#">Rosario, Santa Fe, Argentina.</a> <span class="date">17 de septiembre de 2013.</span>
    </strong>
</div>
```

I want the span to drop into a new line when the width of the div (in the proyect, the viewport) when there's no more space.

Sorry for me bad explanation. I don't know how to do it. Thanks!

Edit: In the second example, the phrase "SEPTIEMBRE DE 2013." drops into a new line. But the phrase "17 DE " is still in the upper line. I want "17 DE SEPTIEMBRE DE 2013." drops into a new line. Got it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want the span to not wrap to a new line, but move entirely below the other text, you can use `white-space: nowrap;`

```
.date {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color:#848484;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/945Df/5/)

Answer (score 18):

To make the span go to the next line when there is not enough space, you can set it to `display: inline-block;`

```
.date {
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}
```

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/945Df/7/

Answer (score 7):

This is how I achieved it:

```
#spantomovedown{
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
.date{display:inline-block;}
```

when the date is longer than the div, it is displayed on a new line

example: http://jsfiddle.net/TqRyK/

Answer (score 1):

If you float:right; it when there is no longer room for the whole thing it should fall to the next line.

You will need a clearing element afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it by
`word-wrap: break word;`