# Span tag cause new line while copying

Tags: html, css

I have some html like:

```
sometext <span style="display: inline; -moz-user-select: none;">₹</span> some other text
```

Now it gives me new line when I copy the whole text

```
sometext 
some other text
```

Is there any way to avoid new line in copied text.

By the way no oncopy handler, looking for html or css way, not the clipboard API or JS.

Sorry my mistake, the test URL:
https://jsfiddle.net/q7zh7wwe/

Actually I am copying to excel, without the span tag it works fine.
With the span tag, I am trying to get just the number to be pasted, but it is creating new line.

Comment: There is a `₹` in your `span` which is not visible. (I don't know how to make it visible) here it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/u9psmd53/

Comment: or you can do this https://jsfiddle.net/u9psmd53/

Comment: This is working fine..may be the issue is browser specific...in which browser you r facing this issue?

Comment: Does not work in Mozilla firefox

Comment: what kind of letter is that in there?  What language, character set, etc.  Are you using UTF-8 unicode?  I tried copying your line and paste into an HTML page and when I copy I get this: `sometext â‚¹ some other text`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a entire span drop into a new line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465765/how-to-make-a-entire-span-drop-into-a-new-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :after and :before for ₹ instead of span tag

Comment: sorry my mistake, put a test url in the question.

Comment: Use :after and :before for ₹ instead of span tag

Comment: works gr8, thanks. I don't know why I was wasting time with filtering spaces for span with span:before when I can have td class:before content set. Sometimes its hard to look for easy solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Using rupee sign like this is not good because its not a character for DOM.

There are entities for so many symbols which should be used to embed any symbol in html. For rupee sign use this `&#x20B9`.

```
sometext <span style="display: inline; -moz-user-select: none;">&#x20B9;</span> some other text
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/u9psmd53/2/

Comment: but that not the question, I my code I am already using &#8377;

Comment: but in your question you mentioned that you are using `₹`..Well make sure utf-8 is given in meta tag like this `<meta charset="UTF-8">`